# 98% European 2% Northern African

Tags: dna

How far back would the ancestor have to be for me to have 2% African?

There is a family story that we are decended from a brother who made some "poor choices' and was disowned from the family.  I guess I thought that if this was the truth that there would be a higher percentage.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no guaranteed way to get the clue what particular ancestor had the African blood.

If you had 50%, I'd guess that one of your parents is 100% African. But in case of grandparents the situation is more complex. Because we don't precisely get 25% of DNA from each of grandparent. The same applies to great grandparents and so on. Also if both parents has, for example, African ancestry, your total count of "African" may be greater than each of parents has.

So you need to get more tests from your relatives. Preferrably - the elder ones (who is from previuos generations). It may help to get additional information and make more solid guesses.